# How to fetch a web page from a web site with URL using the web browser?

Tags: http, url, tcp, port

I have an assignment that reads "You want to use your web browser to fetch a web page from a site called "www.wagstaff.info". Its web server is at TCP port 8080, and the page you are looking for is called "horse.html".Give the URL that you enter into the navigation field of your web browser."

My first thought is that I want to write "www.wagstaff.info/" and then somehow query the web server for the object and retrieve it if it finds it, but i'm not sure if this is the right approach / how to do this.

I actually entered this site and I think the port is miswritten and it should be 80. I tried making a TCP connection to this site with port 80 and it works. I made a GET request for /horse.html and I got 404 Not Found, which makes me believe the page /horse.html doesn't exist on this site in actuality, but it doesn't have to, the assignment just uses the site as an example. But how would I make such a query/request not in cmd using telnet, but instead using the web browser and entering a URL?

If i'm on the correct path here, then, in other words, what do I type after "www.wagstaff.info/" to  query for an object (or page) "/horse.html"? I would expect to get a 404 not found in my web browser, but to me it would mean I have a correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would write the following: www.wagstaff.info:8080/horse.html

the www.wagstaff.info is the domain name that is then resolved to an actual ip address (like 192.168.0.1) what comes after the colon would be the port you're attempting to connect to and everything after that would be the path to the file you're trying to fetch.

Comment: Thank you, the :8080 makes sense in the URL then. But i'm wondering, since I don't actually know the path to the file/page/object (in this case horse.html), I wonder what will happen if I just instantly write /horse.html after the port? Will the server look for the object somehow?

Comment: No, it won't. It will try to find the file in the root of the web server, if it doesn't find it it throws 404 error. You aren't expected to find the file if you don't know the exact path to it.

Comment: but is it then necessary to write the port at all? why not just:www.wagstaff.info/horse.html This will also result in 404

Comment: Because if ommitted the default port would be 80, which is not what they're asking you for. it is the same result but definitely not the same request.